# Could not load ruby textmate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, rvm, textmate

On OS X, after installing Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 4.0.0 via RVM, I get this annoying message every time I open a new terminal window:

```
Unknown ruby interpreter version (do not know how to handle): textmate.
Could not load ruby textmate.
```

The message is in bright red, so it worries me. What can I do to fix it/get rid of it?

Thanks!

EDIT: As it turns out, the message stopped showing, but I can't recall what I did to make it stop.

Comment: You should probably ask this over in SuperUser. If I were to give a guess, I'd say look into `bashrc` and `bash_profile`. The path to TextMate appears to be invalid and it is set as your default IRB editor, which may be why you're getting that warning.

Comment: which shell are you using?

Comment: The shell I'm using is bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check `rvm alias list default` or if you have any `textmate` references in your shell initialization files (`~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bashrc` or similar file)

Answer (score 0):

If you still can't find it, don't forget to look in:

`/etc/profile`

`/etc/profile.d/*`

This happened to me on a new server recently and it ended up being an `rvm.sh` file in the `/etc/profile.d/` directory. Easy to miss!